# How to display expander with Gridview in the wpf

Tags: datagrid

How to display expander  List like line status and need display the line staus details inside expdender if lick line status .
how can implement above like attached image

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2b03.png)

Expander dynamicExpander = new Expander();
GridView grdView = new GridView();

```
        grdView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;
        grdView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Authors";
        GridViewColumn nameColumn = new GridViewColumn();



        nameColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Name");
        nameColumn.Header = "Author Name";
        nameColumn.Width = 120;
        grdView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);


        GridViewColumn ageColumn = new GridViewColumn();

        ageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Age");
        ageColumn.Header = "Age";
        ageColumn.Width = 30;
        grdView.Columns.Add(ageColumn);

        GridViewColumn bookColumn = new GridViewColumn();
        bookColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Book");
        bookColumn.Header = "Button";
        bookColumn.Width = 250;



        grdView.Columns.Add(bookColumn);

       dynamicExpander.Header = "Dynamic Expander";
        
        dynamicExpander.Width = 650;
        dynamicExpander.Height = 400;
        dynamicExpander.IsExpanded = false;
        dynamicExpander.Content = listView;

         RootGrid.Children.Add(dynamicExpander);
```

Here i want to add one column in the all the row View  Button and Multiple list expander same like attached documents